# Remove a contact using Linkedin API.

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I have a platform where people can see their linkedin contacts.

I retrieve those users using the Linkedin API. I would like to give the opportunity to my user to delete some specific Linkedin contact.

Is there any way to remove a user using the Linkedin API ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API call available that will allow you to remove a LinkedIn contact.